# How to access iCSee camera in the browser?

Tags: camera, ip-camera

This WiFi camera is in my local network. I can access through iCSee Android app, but I want to access in the browser.
This is the camera version: RA50X10_C_S

Does anyone know this password?

[This is the printscreen when I try to access in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoH0c.png)

Comment: Have you tried the usual suspects? admin/admin, admin/password, etc..

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback, none of them worked.

Comment: I've found the password, and connect to CMS software, but I can't access by Chrome, it shows: "Your browser is too new,Some features will not work properly.Please download 44.0 or earlier."

Comment: I've used microsoft's Internet Explorer virtual machine [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).

Answer (score 2):

Admin is the user name and the password is whatever you set it to when you connected the camera to Wi-Fi the first time.

If you can't remember it, just do a factory reset on the camera.

Comment: Note that it should be 'admin', all small letters

Answer (score 1):

Unifore has a password recovery web page and tool. From the screen shots on their web page, it looks like the default user is 'admin'. It looks like you use their tool to recover/reset the password.

Unifore.net: [Network/IP security camera reset tool/utility 2019 version](https://www.unifore.net/ip-video-surveillance/forget-ip-security-camera-password-how-to-reset-camera-2019-version.html)